# split the file based on header and footer lines

Tags: linux, awk, sed, split, text-processing

I have a text file structured like this:

```
[timestamp1] header with space
[timestamp2] data1 
[timestamp3] data2
[timestamp4] data3
[timestamp5] ..
[timestamp6] footer with space
[timestamp7] junk
[timestamp8] header with space
[timestamp9] data4
[timestamp10] data5
[timestamp11] ...
[timestamp12] footer with space
[timestamp13] junk
[timestamp14] header with space
[timestamp15] data6
[timestamp16] data7
[timestamp17] data8
[timestamp18] ..
[timestamp19] footer with space
```

I need to find each part between `header` and `footer` and save it in another file. For example the *file1* should contain (with or without timestamps; doesn't matter):

```
data1
data2
data3
..
```

and the next pack should be saved as *file2* and so on.
This seems like a routine process, but I haven't find a solution yet.

I have this *sed* command that finds the first packet.

```
sed -n "/header/,/footer/{p;/footer/q}" file
```

But I don't know how to iterate that over the next matches. Maybe I should delete the first match after copying it to another file and repeat the same command

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: So you want the data extracted **AND** the timestamps removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
[timestamp1] header with space
[timestamp2] data1 
[timestamp3] data2
[timestamp4] data3
[timestamp5] ..
[timestamp6] footer with space
[timestamp7] junk
[timestamp8] header with space
[timestamp9] data4
[timestamp10] data5
[timestamp11] ...
[timestamp12] footer with space
[timestamp13] junk
[timestamp14] header with space
[timestamp15] data6
[timestamp16] data7
[timestamp17] data8
[timestamp18] ..
[timestamp19] footer with space
```

then

```
awk '/header/{c+=1;p=1;next}/footer/{close("file" c);p=0}p{print $0 > ("file" c)}' file.txt
```

produces `file1` with content

```
[timestamp1] header with space
[timestamp2] data1 
[timestamp3] data2
[timestamp4] data3
[timestamp5] ..
```

and `file2` with content

```
[timestamp8] header with space
[timestamp9] data4
[timestamp10] data5
[timestamp11] ...
```

and `file3` with content

```
[timestamp15] data6
[timestamp16] data7
[timestamp17] data8
[timestamp18] ..
```

Explanation: my code has 3 pattern-action pairs, for line containing `header` I increase counter `c` by 1 and set flag `p` to 1 and go to `next` line so no other action is undertaken, for line cotaining `footer` I close file named `file` followed by current counter number and set flag `p` to 0. For lines where `p` is set to true I `print` current line (`$0`) to file named `file` followed by current counter number. If required adjust `/header/` and `/footer/` to contant solely on lines which are header and footer lines.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: useful illustration of awk's basic pattern/action paradigm and clear explanation.

Comment: Nice job avoiding both the "unparenthesised expression" and "too many open files" portability issues.

Answer (score 3):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '/footer/{f=0} f{print > out} /header/{close(out); out="file" (++c); f=1}' file
```

```
$ head file?*
==> file1 <==
[timestamp2] data1
[timestamp3] data2
[timestamp4] data3
[timestamp5] ..

==> file2 <==
[timestamp9] data4
[timestamp10] data5
[timestamp11] ...

==> file3 <==
[timestamp15] data6
[timestamp16] data7
[timestamp17] data8
[timestamp18] ..
```

Answer (score 2):

A very naive approach, coded fast, could be improved, but seems to work, in awk:

```
BEGIN {
    i = 0
}
{
    if ($0 == "header") {
        write = 1
    } else if ($0 == "footer") {
        write = 0
        i = i + 1
    } else {
        if (write == 1) {
            print $0 > "file"i
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot about the timestamps in each line. This works great without timstamps. Is there a way to get it working with timestamps?

Comment: @mehdi You can just remove the timestamps before piping into this script.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yeah I got it. Using `~` instead of `==` in the string matching also works.

Comment: I think you should check if the end of the string contains footer or header, in case footer or header is in the actual data. (you can split the line on space et check the last element of the array)

Comment: Has the "unparenthesised expression" and "too many open files" portability issues.

Comment: @EdMorton What do you mean ?

Comment: @Itération122442 `print $0 > "file"i` is undefined behavior in POSIX and so will be a syntax error in some awks, you have to put parens around any expression used in input or output redirection for it to work in all awks, e.g. `print $0 > ("file"i)`. Also, if you don't call `close()` to close the output files as you go then awk is just continuously opening more and more files and at some point will exceed a threshold and fail saying "too many open files" or if you're using gawk it'll slow down significantly as it tries to internally handle closing/re-opening files to avoid that error.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU csplit and sed):

```
csplit -qf file -b '%d' --supp file '/header/' '{*}' && sed -i '/footer/,$d' file? && rm file0
```

Use csplit to split `file` into multiple `filen` files on `header` suppressing the matching line.

Use sed to delete `footer` and any following lines`.

Remove the unwanted `file0` file.

---

Alternative:

```
sed -En '/header/{x;s/.*/echo $((0&+1))/e;x};/header/,/footer/!b;//b;G;s/(.*)\n/echo "\1" >>file/e' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [THIS REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/gNC0xo/1), here is a ruby:

```
ruby -e 'cnt=1
$<.read.scan(/^.*\bheader\b.*\s+([\s\S]*?)(?=^.*\bfooter\b)/){
    |b| File.write("File_#{cnt}.txt", b[0])
    cnt+=1
}' file
```

Produces:

```
$ head File_*
==> File_1.txt <==
[timestamp2] data1 
[timestamp3] data2
[timestamp4] data3
[timestamp5] ..

==> File_2.txt <==
[timestamp9] data4
[timestamp10] data5
[timestamp11] ...

==> File_3.txt <==
[timestamp15] data6
[timestamp16] data7
[timestamp17] data8
[timestamp18] ..
```

If you want to remove the timestamps:

```
ruby -e 'cnt=1
$<.read.scan(/^.*\bheader\b.*\s+([\s\S]*?)(?=^.*\bfooter\b)/){ |b| 
    File.write("File_#{cnt}.txt", b[0].gsub(/^\[[^\]]+\]\s+/,""))
    cnt+=1
}' file 

$ head File_*
==> File_1.txt <==
data1 
data2
data3
..

==> File_2.txt <==
data4
data5
...

==> File_3.txt <==
data6
data7
data8
..
```

Note: If you want to include the header and/or footer, just move the capture group to include what you want.